# \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} Only Changes the Font in Bold

Tags: fonts, helvetica

I'd like to change the font of the entire document to Helvetica. However, as the title says, \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} only changes the font in bold. The rest remains as is. What should be done to fix this partial change and have the whole document to be in Helvetica? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show an complete example document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: it will not change the font at that point, only from the next font change. add `\normalfont` if you want the font to change at the point that you make this declaration.

Comment: @David Carlisle, that seems to work but you have to have it interspersed randomly here and there in the text, where needed. Also, math isn't changing font.

Comment: @ganzewoort sorry it is impossible to guess what you have done if you do not show any example. helvetica is not a math font and in any case changing the default text font will not affect math at all.

Comment: note that `\sfdefault` is not helvetica (unless you have other commands that you have not shown to make it helvetica) it is computer modern sans serif with its initial definition.

Comment: @David Carlisle, of course, I have prior \usepackage{tgheros}. As for the math, I just tried \usepackage{arevmath} and it seems to work. For now I'll live with your suggestion to include \normalfont where necessary. I accept your answer.

Comment: you shouldn't need \normalfont anywhere, you presumably set the default in the wrong place but I can not guess where.

Answer (score 6):

Write

```
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

In your preamble.

Comment: OMG I've been looking for these posts for days. Nothing on StackOverflow in detail about customizing the PDF fonts and styling for Jupyter Notebook and nbconvert when exporting to PDF.  So I followed your directions and now all is beautiful with sfdefault. Next....This did not change the super ugly fonts in the code cells. Especially the python comments. The PDF is using the horrendous cursive fonts. Please tell me how to change that. I am in the same article.tplx file now. Is it easy? Please add it to your answer. Many people are looking for this. Thanks!

Comment: I want to change this atrocity. https://imgur.com/TvqB5Mc

Answer (score 5):

It will not change the font at that point, only from the next font change. add `\normalfont` if you want the font to change at the point that you make this declaration.

Comment: What do you mean at the point of declaration? In the preamble? I added `\usepackage{helvet}` and `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` like Hugh said below and it seems to work. Is that ok? How would I change the Jupyter code cell font? And what kind of fonts are recommended for notebook typography?

Comment: I want to change this https://imgur.com/TvqB5Mc